# Expose public transit ticket activity via intent action

Tags: android, android-intent

I am currently working on a public transit ticket application. 
I know there is a 'reserve taxi' Intent and are looking for the 'buying a train ticket' equivalent.

Comment: "I know there is a 'reserve taxi' Intent" -- what do you mean by "a 'reserve taxi' Intent"?

Comment: I might be wrong but from https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html there is a ACTION_RESERVE_TAXI_RESERVATION action.

Comment: That's part of Play Services. They do not have `Intent` actions for every possible transaction, and I do not see where they have one for purchasing a train ticket.